# How do I access a HTML file in an Eclipse Project?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to open a local HTML file located in my Eclipse Project Folder. Here my code:

```
String baseURL = "http://www.google.com";
selenium1 = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(progressDriver, baseURL);
        selenium1.open("outputtter.html");
        progressDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        selenium1.refresh();
```

This is not working. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Which OS are you working on? What is the error message?

Comment: Java. Page not found on this Server once the WebDriver operns.

Comment: Have a look at this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/selenium-users/Te_BP3BZAUE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
selenium1.open("/outputtter.html");  //check the path here.
                     This depends on from where you are exactly accessing
```